# Rewrite join to ANSI syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
select ... fields
from table a, b
where ... conditions
and a.timeload between b.timestop(+) and b.timego(+)
```

I do understand how **between** operator works and I know that **+** operator here stands for **left join**. How do I rewrite it using ANSI joins standard?

Comment: TIP: don't use the ANSI standard if you don't have to. very buggy. you wont see it coming ! the only time you really need it is for FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Yes I've heard about it. But I haven't got used to Oracle joins notation yet.

Comment: i know man. i had to put on a poster in my office to remind me where the `(+)` sign should be..... (it's where you want the nulls). good luck !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `+` operator.

For your query, it is `a LEFT OUTER JOIN b`:

```
select ... fields
from table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.timeload between b.timestop and b.timego
where ... conditions
```